# c# image transfer to c++ [DllImport]

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dllimport

I am currently transfer my image to the c++ library over a pointer `IntPtr pArray` and use openCV for decode. But now we want remove the dependency to openCV. For the new implementation we would like to transfer a struct `image_t`. How i can convert a png or jpeg file in c# to this format? Is there a better solution available?

```
int detect_mat(image_t img) {
   ...
}

struct image_t {
    int h;                        // height
    int w;                        // width
    int c;                        // number of channels (3 - for RGB)
    float *data;                  // pointer to the image data
};
```

**My current implementation**

c#

```
[DllImport("Library", EntryPoint = "detect_mat")]
internal static extern int DetectImage(IntPtr pArray, int nSize);

public void Detect(byte[] imageData)
{
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(imageData[0]) * imageData.Length;
    var pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

    Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, pnt, imageData.Length);
    DetectImage(pnt, imageData.Length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
}
```

c++

```
int detect_mat(const uint8_t* data, const size_t data_length) {
    std::vector<char> vdata(data, data + data_length);
    cv::Mat image = imdecode(cv::Mat(vdata), 1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What format does the c++ code want?

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan it is for the yolo project to Transfer the Images into the c++ logic https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/4614#issuecomment-570373461